# how to get other person's schedule using python api O365

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, calendar, office365

I am trying to get other person's availability time (displayed on outlook). 
My company uses Office 365 for managing appointments. So, I write down these programs to get the data.
i can get my schedule using following program, but i don't know how to get to other people's schedule.

```
schedule = account.schedule()
calendar = schedule.get_default_calendar()
q = calendar.new_query('start').greater_equal(calDay + ' 00:00:00')
q.chain('and').on_attribute('end').less_equal(calDay + ' 23:59:59')
cal = calendar.get_events(query=q, order_by='end/dateTime', download_attachments=True, include_recurring=True)
```

I'm just guessing, but I can't get other's schedules using python api O365?
(Do I have to use just microsoft graph api?)

I would appreciate it if you could answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `get_availability` method of `Schedule` class. It is now included in version `2.0.4` [released on 18th Oct](https://pypi.org/project/O365/#history) - last Friday. It can do exactly what you want it to do from what I see.

[Issue with request to add this feature.](https://github.com/O365/python-o365/issues/329)

[Commit with the feature.](https://github.com/O365/python-o365/commit/5d546f0818941f991469cdbc7a1853493ba01ee2)